# How to get value from a text field inside a table column with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I've created an auto-gen table with input text field in the column. Therefore, all the input text field id is the same.

```
$(document).on('click', '.oc-save-upgrade-downgrade-rules', function (event) {

    //sel - retrieve which row id was checked in checkbox
    var sel = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked('oc-list-upgradeRule', 'chkbox');

    //just a validation if non of the checkbox is check
    var row = $.fn.yiiGridView.getRow('oc-list-upgradeRule');

    //row - use row id to select entire row
    if (typeof sel !== 'undefined' && sel.length > 0){
        var row = $.fn.yiiGridView.getRow('oc-list-upgradeRule', sel);
    }

    //this has successfully get the value but always get the first row because all input text field use the same id
    var ipt = document.getElementById("indaysText").value;

    //currently this only able to retrieve a td segment, [5] means where the input text field are
    var input = $(row[5]);

    console.log(ipt);
    console.log(input);
})
```

Currently with this $(row[5]), I was only able to retrieve

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
     <input type="text" value="365" name="indays" id="indays">
</td>
```

It gets the entire "td", so the value is null. How should I get the entire "input" instead or directly get the input value?

Comment: `all input text field use the same id` there's your problem, having more than one element with the same ID is invalid HTML. Change it to a class instead

Comment: It is not a proper way to give same id to all input but still You can find by var input = $(row[5] input);

Comment: @Nirali Ya, I know it was not a proper way, but for the time being, I didn't quite get what you mean by var input = $(row[5] input);

Comment: Change From var input = $(row[5]);  to   var input = $(row[5] input); in your code and see output of console.log(input);

Comment: @Nirali Ya, I follow your solution, but it show this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'input'. Expected ')' to end an argument list."

Comment: Can you please try var input = $(row[5]); var temp = input.find("input"); and then show console.log(temp);